# Changing Widget Image by OnClick (or PendingIntent ?)

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like my Appwidget in addition to the main function nor (Widget)images changed.

When calling the function `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1001, new Intent(context, Counter.class), 0);` should also change the widget to the new image.

Then, when the requested activity exits, the widget will switch to the old image. The `Counter.class` itself has no layout - so I can still see the homescreen with the widget when activity is running. Why would that the widget displays through changing the picture that the activity is running or rather not.
But I have no idea how to do it.
My WidgetProvider code:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    for (int i = appWidgetIds.length; --i >= 0;) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, Counter.class), 0);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.count_widget);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.countWidget, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my English :)